# Getting the current user information

Tags: nsis

I been using NSIS for simple installers. I am now at a point where i need to install files to a user's specific location. For example, in my case, the palette directory where i need to put the new palettes is C:\Users\Russ\Documents\My Palettes.

How can i determine, automatically, the current user (Russ) when the installer executes. (Or is this something i have to prompt the user for?)

I've looked at other NSIS constants, but couldn't find something particular for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My documents is listed in the constants list.

```
MessageBox mb_ok "$Documents\My Palettes"
```

Comment: It's about the 15th Constant in the Docuemntation: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.2.3